# Two simple questions regarding typesetting maths (in LaTeX)

Tags: soft-question, article-writing

The first question I have regards endomorphisms, especially in differential geometry. Everyone who had worked a little in (complex) differential geometry will know that it is very common to write the action of the complex structure $J$ on vector fields without parenthesis, i.e. $JX$ instead of $J(X)$. I suppose that is because of matrix notation, altough I'm not sure. And the same applies to general endomorphisms; it's quite strange to find $L(X)$ in papers. What do you think about? Which one do you prefer? It would be nice to open a little debat with the answers.

The other one also appears in differential geometry, I think it can be extended to any other field though. Suppose that we agree endomorphisms must be typesetted with brackets. Then, consider an endomorphism acting over a Lie bracket. Would you typeset

$$J([X,Y])$$

or

$$J\big([X,Y]\big)$$

(the second uses the comand `\big` because `\left` `\right` has no effect)?
Or consider an endomorphism acting over a horizontal lift. What would you typeset: $J(X^h)$ or $J\left(X^h\right)$ (now the second uses the ``` \left``\right ```command)?

I mean, does a parenthesis have to cover the content inside always? I mean, all of us agree that

$$(\frac{1}{12}+1)$$

looks horrible but... what happens when the difference is more subtle, as the cases I have mentioned? again it would be nice if we created a little discussion about that.

---

By the way, I have used `article-writing`tag because it's the unique that talks about that I think, but feel free to modify it if necessary.

Comment: I personally try to always incorporate the \left and \right commands whenever there is a chance that it changes the output.

Comment: Larger parentheses are useful when it is hard for the eye to group things; $J(X^h)$ does not produce problems, and causes less text disruption than $J\left(X^h\right)$ (using left and right custom-sized parentheses). In a displayed equation you might want the latter, but not in-line when there just isn’t that much of a problem. Otherwise, you are pushing lines apart as well.

Comment: I agree with @ArturoMagidin that the most important is that you can parse the expression with the less effort as possible. Also, I think $J\left(X^h\right)$ is also not optimal because of the spacing after the $J$. Of course, this is unless $J$ is a constant and you want to multiply $(X^h)$ by $J$. But in this case, would write `J \, (X^h)` which produces $J\, (X^h)$.

Comment: Yes, it's true that you don't want to modify line separation in formulas displayed in the text. And I haven't seen the extra space added by the `left` `right` command, it's true is rather strange @Surb.

Comment: @MattiP. I agree with you, I think `LaTeX` is cleverer than me. However it seems sometimes it isn't the best...

Comment: And what do you think about the firts question? I guess you will prefer $JX$ than $J(X)$...

Comment: Also note that there's a [latex stack exchange forum](https://tex.stackexchange.com).

Comment: @ViktorGlombik Yes but I haven't seen any `tag` this question could fit in. In fact, the chosen tag isn't the best in my opinion but it was the 'least worse'.

Comment: The first question is about standards of notation in particular fields. That’s a separate question, and is not really about LaTeX-ing or how to write an article, but about using the common practices of the field you are working in.